# iPhone application that submits info to a website and gets results back

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development, I wonder where could I find:

1) the best tutorials to start iPhone programming
2) info or code about how to submit info to a website (example search query to google) and get data back (show summary of query results on iphone)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well Stanford University has a whole EXTREMELY helpful iTunes U series on the iPhone development process. That should help you. Good luck and HAVE FUN.

Answer (score 0):

As a new iPhone developer myself, I've found apple's sdk documentation to be the best for learning.  The [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/index.html) package has been my go to for figuring things out.  It's got a little bit of everything in it.

I tried to do web tutorials - there are a ton out there, just search iPhone tutorial on the web or on SO - but I found most of them lacking.

There are a couple of classes that you can you use to retrieve a web request.  [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) will be the best one for making POST requests, and if you're querying restful services [initializing an NSString with a URL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW15) is the easiest method.